# Swift SQLite SQL Count

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift, int32

In a Swift iOS 8 project with SQLite, I'm trying to get the number of rows in a table using the SQL `COUNT` function. From the examples I found in C, I came with this code:

```
var nRows: Int32 = 0

func getNquestions() {
    let querySQL = "SELECT COUNT(*) from table"
    let results:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(querySQL,withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    if results?.next() == true {
        nRows = results?.intForColumnIndex(0) //STATEMENT GENERATING ERROR
    }
}
```

After getting a type mismatch error I changed the definition of nRows to Int32 but I keep getting compilation errors (this time "Value of optional type 'Int32? not unwrapped."

Any clues?

Answer (score 1):

You declare at the beginning of this function that `nRows` is `Int32`, not `Int32?`. Meanwhile, the result of `results?.intForColumnIndex(0)` returns `Int32?` due to optional chaining (and perhaps additionally due to the fact that `intForColumnIndex()` may return an optional).

You must either change your declaration:

```
var nRows: Int32?
```

Or use `if`–`let` to assign:

```
if let results = results where results.next() {
    nRows = results.intForColumnIndex(0)
}
```

(You could also force-unwrap, but it's safer to avoid doing so.)

Answer (score 1):

Try with the statement like this.

```
SELECT count() FROM contacts
```

It worked for me. Notice the count syntax without "*".